What are all the triggers or 'signals' in Signal 100?
I saw the live-action Signal 100 film (2019), and saw the board with all the other 'signals' on it, but it never got translated in the film, in the version I saw at least. It is based on a manga, but since I have not read it and it is seemingly not very popular, I could not find them.
Does anyone have a complete list of all the triggers? I know crying, acting violent, reading comics, using phones, drinking from bottles, staring too long at someone, leaving school grounds, beer showers, non-authorized clothing, having 7 people pointing at you all at once, touching sexually stimulated parts, and staying at school until dawn are all triggers for suicide, at least in the film, maybe not in the manga.
Please share the rest if they are known.

Please don't post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites.

I only did so as it is both a manga and film, so I thought I would cover both bases. @F1Krazy

@F1Krazy I think it's fine. The questions address different things. This one's about the film (which is off-topic in Anime & Manga SE), while the other one's about the manga (which is off-topic here).
